# Developer tools , in Chrome, anyway to capture network log from all tabs

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to capture all the traffic from different tabs in chrome developer tools? I see if i open tab it captures only traffic originated from that tab. My case is like I am not able to see the traffic for cases like when you click on a file it creates a request in a new tab and then downloads the file. Could not get this request as part of the har.

Answer (score 2):

You can't capture requests from multiple tabs in one instance of DevTools because it's tab specific.

However, you can use the `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag when opening Chrome to auto-open the DevTools panel when new tabs are loaded. This means you will be able to capture your requests from the new tab as the page loads.

**Windows:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

**OSX:**

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

You can also use "Auto-open DevTools for popups" option in the DevTools setting panel to cover when popup windows are open too.

[image]